# IndexOutOfBoundsException ArrayList Error

Tags: java

I'm writing a basic java card game but I'm getting a
`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size 6 (in java.util.ArrayList` error on this bit of code, could you help me please?

```
 public void simple() { 
        if (cards.get(cards.size()-1).getSuit().equals(cards.get(cards.size()).getSuit())) { 

            int last=cards.size()-1;
            Card c=cards.remove(last);
            cards.set(last-1,c);

        }
        else {
            System.out.println("hi");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at line 2 and remember that Java starts indexing with 0. This means the contents of your arraylist go from 0 to cards.size() - 1 (exclusive).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling `cards.get(cards.size())` will fail every time.

This is because they're 0 indexed. So if you have size 6, your indexes are `0,1,2,3,4,5`.

If you want the last two cards, use `cards.get(cards.size()-2)` and `cards.get(cards.size()-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem occurs on your second line with the code `cards.get(cards.size())`.

Indices for lists in Java start at 0 so `cards.size()` would, by definition, be accessing an element outside the `cards` collection and throwing the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.  The last element in `cards will always be at`cards.size()-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem: `cards.get(cards.size())`

An `ArrayList` is just like an array - if it has 6 elements in it, then the index of the last item is 5 (since arrays start at index 0, not 1).